# 3D numpy recarray

Tags: pandas, numpy, recarray

```
# pre-allocate data cube
cube = np.empty((len(time_ix), len(data_ix), len(id_ix)))
cube[:] = np.NaN
# filling of cube
tix=3
idx=5
data = cube[tix,:,idx]
```

Data is describing the values of 20 columns roughly at that day for that id

I am creating a cube to slice better my data afterwards, unfortunately by using such statement I can fill my 2nd dimension with the data having data type only `float64` that turned to be quite expensive in terms of storage.
I didn't find a way to declare the above mentioned cube as a rec array, in such a way that I could fit into the `data_ix` dimension heterogeneous data types.

Alternatively, is there a way to represent a 3d array (cube) with 2 indexes to easily slic (time and id) to get the according dataset with pandas dataframes?

Comment: A `pandas` dataframe is a 2d object (in the simplest case with uniform column `dtype`).  It may have columns with names like "x, y, z", representing point coordinates in 3d space.  But that's very different from a 3d numpy array.  Be careful when equating numpy 3d with a "cube".

Comment: Sure @hpaulj - I think you got my idea though, if you feel like I should change something in my question to make it clear please go ahead and I will approve the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

Use a 2-D rec array

```
x = np.array([[(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], [(0.0, 1), (7.0, 5)]], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i8')])
```

Then

```
x['x']

array([[1., 3.],
       [0., 7.]])
```

Gives a float array while

```
x['y']

array([[2, 4],
       [1, 5]], dtype=int64)
```

gives an integer array

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I am not sure this fits my needs and please feel free to suggest a better explanation in case I was not clear.
By using the `cube` I mentioned before I could access my dataset my selecting `cube[1,:,5]` as dummy example: how could I do the same with a 2D recarray? 
Basically once selected the time index and the id index, I would retrieve the values of 18 columns, that might even be a dataframe if it would fit different data structures

Comment: Instead of `cube[1, :, 5]` you slice just two dimensions and specify the field.  In my example `x[1, :]['y']`.  The first two dimensions are as you expect.  The 3rd dimension is just the record itself which has several fields.